# How can I combine data from form and from three mysql tables to insert data in another table with php?

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

```
sql="INSERT INTO maticna
   (formCompany,formPlace,formDate,formPerson,formCollect
   ,formOffer,formDescribe,formBarkod,formSubject,formWorking
   ,formStatus,formRevision) 
SELECT 
  company.formCompany, company.formPlace
  , $formDate AS formDate
  , $formPerson AS formPerson
  , $formCollect AS formCollect
  , $formOffer AS formOffer
  , $formDescribe AS formDescribe
  , $formBarkod AS formBarkod
  , inv.formSubject, work.rnNo
  , $formStatus AS formStatus
  , $formRevision AS formRevision)"
 ."FROM company, inv, work 
 WHERE inv.formBarkod='$formBarkod'";
```

Something doesn't work with this code? Could anyone help with this code or some better method?

Comment: there ia ans extra `)`. btw what error u r getting by above method??

Comment: @MasterCassim, it doesn't write nothing to table

Answer (score 2):

```
$formDate = mysql_real_escape_string($formdate);
$formPerson = mysql_real_escape_string($formPerson);
....
//For each and every $var you inject in the SQL statement.

$sql="INSERT INTO maticna
   (formCompany,formPlace,formDate,formPerson,formCollect
   ,formOffer,formDescribe,formBarkod,formSubject,formWorking
   ,formStatus,formRevision) 
SELECT 
  c.formCompany, c.formPlace
  , '$formDate' AS formDate
  , '$formPerson' AS formPerson
  , '$formCollect' AS formCollect
  , '$formOffer' AS formOffer
  , '$formDescribe' AS formDescribe
  , '$formBarkod' AS formBarkod
  , i.formSubject, w.rnNo
  , '$formStatus' AS formStatus
  , '$formRevision' AS formRevision
FROM company c
INNER JOIN work w ON (w.id = i.work_id)
INNER JOIN inv i ON (i.company_id = c.id)
WHERE i.formBarkod= '$formBarkod' ";
```

**Mistakes you make**
1. Don't use implicit join syntax, it leads to cross joins; always use explicit join syntax instead.
2. You did not have any join criteria.
3. All $vars need to be escaped always.
4. All $vars, be they numbers or not need to be quoted in the SQL-statement.
5. Minor syntax error in the insert statement.

Comment: I'm allways using escaped $vars but  I didn't wrote it here. Thank you, I'll try your code soon.

Comment: @mdakic, do note that `mysql_real_escape_string()` only works **if** you quote your $vars. If you don't then it doesn't work!

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you insert VALUES before the select?

```
INSERT INTO maticna (...) VALUES (SELECT ...)
```

Comment: INSERT...SELECT is valid.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html